# Chrome DevTools Protocol Implementation

Tags: puppeteer, chrome-devtools-protocol

I am trying to collect specific data from CDP using the protocol, I tried using Selenium or Puppeteer but I am not getting all the Networks metrics I am trying to collect. See the list here:
(https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Network/)
Can someone help find a way, library, or resources to help me collect those data from Chrome browse through a webpage workload?

I tried this but the data collected is not consistent enough.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
const PuppeteerHar = require('puppeteer-har');
const fs = require('fs');
const prompt = require('prompt-sync')();
const json_to_csv = require('json-2-csv');

async function main() {

    let url = prompt('Enter URL: (example https://www.google.com ) ');

    const browser = await puppeteer.launch(
        {
            headless: true,
            defaultViewport: false,
            args: ['--no-sandbox']
        }
    );
    const page = await browser.newPage();

    const har = new PuppeteerHar(page);

    await har.start({ path: 'results.json' });

    await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });

    await page.waitForTimeout(30000);

    await har.stop();

    let data = fs.readFileSync('results.json');

    data = JSON.parse(data);

    data = data['log']['entries'];

    let csv = await json_to_csv.json2csvAsync(data);

    console.log(csv);

    fs.writeFile('data.csv', csv, function(err) {
        if (err) {
            console.log(err);
        }
    }
    );

    await browser.close();
};

main();
```